# makefile minify files

Tags: makefile

The code below does not work but meant to illustrate what I want to achieve.  How can I make this code work or is there a better way.  I want to combine all my CSS files into one file, but want to make sure all files under BASE_CSS is at the top of that file.

```
BASE_CSS = %reset.css %reset2.css %reset3.css
IGNORE_CSS = %main.min.css $(BASE_CSS)

CSS_FILES = $(filter-out $(IGNORE_CSS),$(wildcard \
  public/css/*.css \
  public/css/*/*.css \
  public/css/*/*/*.css \
))

minify:
  cat $(BASE_CSS) $(CSS_FILES) > public/css/main.min.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what I think you want:

```
# Note the ":=".
# If we use "=", it will run "find" every time ALL_CSS_FILES is mentioned.
ALL_CSS_FILES := $(shell find public/css -name *.css)

BASE_PATTERN = %reset.css %reset2.css %reset3.css

BASE_CSS = $(filter $(BASE_PATTERN), $(ALL_CSS_FILES))

CSS_FILES = $(filter-out $(BASE_PATTERN) %main.min.css, $(ALL_CSS_FILES))

minify:
        cat $(BASE_CSS) $(CSS_FILES) > public/css/main.min.css
```

**EDIT:**
To specify the order, just do this:

```
BASE_CSS = $(filter %reset.css, $(ALL_CSS_FILES))
BASE_CSS += $(filter %reset2.css, $(ALL_CSS_FILES))
BASE_CSS += $(filter %reset3.css, $(ALL_CSS_FILES))
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to specify the order of reset.css, reset2.css, and reset3.css?